GeoServer does not fill native SRS for PostGIS layer
When creating a new vector layer from a PostGIS JNDI datasource, the field Native SRS keeps being empty.
Declared SRS is correctly set to EPSG:4326.
I know there already exist some posts on this topic and I have checked the hints from others:
Geoserver - empty native SRS field
Layer missing Native SRS in geoserver
that is, I have checked that my user used by GeoServer to access the table has the relevant permissions.
SELECT * FROM information_schema.table_privileges

Gives me all privileges on my table.
The same is true for
SELECT * FROM information_schema.column_privileges 

I have also checked, that
SELECT Find_SRID('public', 'mytable', 'the_geom');

returns find_srid = '4326'
What else can be the issue that GeoServer does not recognize the SRS of my data?

You say you have permissions for the table and metadata, does GeoServer have permissions too? what does the log file say?

Geoserver uses the same user via the JNDI connection that I use to connect to the db.
In the Geoserver log, I don't see recent error messages that I'd consider relevant.
